# Using Oracle's CREATE SEQUENCE as secure random

Tags: oracle, security, random, sequence

I was wondering if Oracle's CREATE SEQUENCE with NOORDER statement ([enabled by default](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm#sthref7331)) could be used as a secure random number generator ?
I mean, is it really random or it could be predicted ?

I couldn't find doc regarding to this spec.

Thanks in advance.
lemon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  If you want random numbers, use the [`dbms_crypto` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#i1001225).

A sequence with `NOORDER` specified will still give sequential, ordered numbers in a non-RAC system.  If you are using RAC, however, each node will have a separate cache of values and one node will be generating values that are greater than the other nodes at the same time.  For example, if you have a 3 node cluster and a sequence with a cache of 20, node 1 would cache the values 1-20, node 2 would cache the values 21-40, and node 3 would cache the values 41-60.  If a session on node 3 requested the `nextval`, it would get 41.  Then, if another session on node 1 requested the `nextval`, it would get the value 1.  The next request on node 3 would get 42, the next request on node 1 would get 2, the next request on node 2 would get 21.  And, of course, once each node exhausted its cache, it would cache the next 20 values.  If one node persistently gets more `nextval` requests, it can get much further ahead of the `nextval` on the other nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your complete response, that answers my question.